# xcode ios publish fails

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I have set CFBundleShortVersionString & CFBundleVersion in App_Resources/iOS/info.plist as

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0.0.0</string>
```

using nativescript:

tns-ios: 2.1.0
tns --version: 2.1.0

here is the tns publish ios output:

```
ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/<XYZ>.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."
ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/<XYZ>.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."
```

For some reason it does not find the mentioned key. Any ideas?
Thanks

**Update:**

Open platforms/ios/Internal/NativeScript.framework/Info.plist in **Xcode**.

change bundle Version : 2.1.0
add bundle versions string, short : 2.1

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in v2.1 of NativeScript; you actually need to modify the

> /platforms/ios/Internal/NativeScript.framework/Info.plist

file with those two keys.

See: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2397